# Inserir ID em Tabela com 13.346 linhas com LOOP

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estou precisando atualizar uma tabela com 13 mil linhas. E essa tabela contem um campo chamado "faixa_cep_id" e todos os ids estão 0. Preciso atualizar isso com um loop para não duplicar os campos (EX: 1, 2, 3, 4...). Alguém poderia dar essa ajuda?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pl_joseanmatias_faixa_cep_peso`;
CREATE TABLE `pl_joseanmatias_faixa_cep_peso` (
  `faixa_cep_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `weight_min` float NOT NULL,
  `weight_max` float NOT NULL,
  `postcode_min` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postcode_max` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cost` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Os dados que você quer inserir vem de outra tabela? Se vem, existe um relacionamento entre a tabela que quer alterar e a tabela aonde se encontra os dados? Sua pergunta ficou meio vaga, especifique com um exemplo.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão não... Quero que inicie a inserção de ids automaticamente contando a partir de 1.
Ficando:
1
2
3
4

Mas sem interferir nos outros campos da tabela...

Comment: Ahhhh, você quer um campo de auto-incremento? Ou seja, faixa_cep_id conta de 1 até as 13 mil correto?

Comment: @RafaelSalomão isso mesmo :D

Comment: @RafaelSalomão aconteceu um erro. Tentei te marcar la em baixo mas não consegui

Comment: @RafaelSalomão atualizei o post com uma sql pra criação da tabela

Comment: @RafaelSalomão e como eu faço isso?

Comment: Não vejo coluna de auto-incremento na sua tabela. Você definiu o atributo : faixa_cep_id como índice? Ela tem que ser um indice de sua tabela. Postei lá em baixo como cria o indice.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão 
#1062 - Entrada '0' duplicada para a chave 'faixa_cep_id'

Comment: Porque o indíce que mandei definir é do tipo indice unico e sua coluna contém valores duplicados. crie um indice simples apenas : " ALTER TABLE `faixa_cep_id` ADD INDEX `ID` (`ID`); "   também funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para adicionar um atributo novo em sua tabela e definir ele como auto-incremento pode rodar um **ALTER TABLE** dessa forma :

```
ALTER TABLE `nome_tabela`
ADD COLUMN `faixa_cep_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Exemplo se a coluna já existir :

```
ALTER TABLE `nome_tabela`
CHANGE COLUMN `faixa_cep_id` `faixa_cep_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Atualização :

Crie o índice :

```
ALTER TABLE `pl_joseanmatias_faixa_cep_peso`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `faixa_cep_id` (`faixa_cep_id`);
```

Em seguida dê o alter table criando um atributo auto-increment

```
ALTER TABLE `pl_joseanmatias_faixa_cep_peso`
CHANGE COLUMN `faixa_cep_id` `faixa_cep_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

PS: A cada nova linha o própio banco de dados já insere a numeração automaticamente para você. Então não precisa mexer em nenhum **INSERT** seu.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `pl_joseanmatias_faixa_cep_peso`
ADD COLUMN `faixa_cep_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1075 - Definição incorreta de tabela. Somente é permitido um único campo auto-incrementado e ele tem que ser definido como chave

Comment: apareceu o seguinte erro:
#1075 - Definição incorreta de tabela. Somente é permitido um único campo auto-incrementado e ele tem que ser definido como chave

Comment: Então deu isso porque na sua tabela já existe um campo definido como auto-increment. E ele só aceita um atributo com auto-increment. Nesse caso poste a estrutura da tabela vou montar um querie que faz isso.

Comment: Consegui criar o indice assim: 
CREATE INDEX id_faixa_de_cep ON pl_joseanmatias_faixa_cep_peso (faixa_cep_id);

E rodei o change column...

Muito obrigado pela ajuda @RafaelSalomão :D

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Rafael já resolve o seu problema.
Mas caso queira apenas atualizar os dados sem ter que alterar
o tipo da coluna, segue um exemplo:

```
declare @i int
set @i =0
while @i < 13346
begin
BEGIN TRAN

update  pl_joseanmatias_faixa_cep_peso set faixa_cep_id = SELECT @i + 1
COMMIT TRAN;
set @i =@i + 1
end
```

Comment: Consegui com o autoincrement... Mesmo assim muito obrigado @MarcosMarques ^^